# Enable MFA Delete on S3 AWS Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I,

I want to enable "MFA delete" on AWS S3 bucket. The official doc (cf http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete)

I don't know what is the "serial number" for the MFA ?

it seems quite hard to write a python code to generate the right signed headers. Do you have any advice for me ? (an existing python script for example ! :p)

The official code snippet :

```
PUT /?versioning HTTPS/1.1 
Host: BucketName .s3.amazonaws.com 
Date: Date 
Authorization: Signature 
Content-Type: ContentType 
Content-Length: Length-of-Content 
x-amz-mfa: [SerialNumber] [AuthenticationCode] 

<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> 
<Status> Enabled </Status> 
<MfaDelete> Enabled </MfaDelete> 
</VersioningConfiguration>
```

Comment: What type of MFA are you using? Hardware or software?

Comment: Hi, THanks for your answer. Using Virtual MFA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is virtual MFA, then just give the ARN of the virtual MFA device as the serial number. The authentication code is the current code shown on the device. You can get the ARN from IAM dashboard or by executing the CLI:

```
$ aws iam list-mfa-devices
{
    "MFADevices": [
        {
            "UserName": "obama",
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::1234827366789:mfa/obama",
            "EnableDate": "2015-09-16T18:47:44Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need a python example: [mfa_delete](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920020202/s3_mfa_delete.py)

Comment: The correct command for listing virtual mfa devices is `aws iam list-virtual-mfa-devices`. Or, like helloV says, you can get the ARN from the IAM dashboard at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/security_credential and click the MFA dropdown section (region in url doesn't matter)