# Enable AWS S3 MFA delete with the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to enable AWS S3 MFA delete with the console? How?

I don't manage to find any way to do it, neither have found any answer googling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No - you can enable versioning on the bucket but you cannot enable MFA delete.

You can do it via the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-versioning.html):

`aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucketname --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "your-mfa-serial-number mfa-code"`

Note that the command above also enables bucket versioning.

Comment: I am getting error for aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket test-bucket-mfa --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "xxxxx"..............An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: Mfa header is invalid -- the header should be formatted as {serialNumber}(space){tokenCode}

Comment: Is it that I have to run this command I should have to configure cli with roots accounts secret key access key any other user is fine ?

Comment: Add `--profile <PROFILE_NAME>` if you have multiple profiles configured. FYI, I like keeping my email ID as profile name in order to remember and be unique.

Comment: Yep, several things to note:
your-mfa-serial-number = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395408/enable-mfa-delete-on-s3-aws-bucket.
mfa-code = the 6-digit number you get from your google authenticator or whatever mfa device.
This must be done from root access credentials, and only with a root MFA token.

Comment: Note: This is one of the few policies where you MUST use the root account, you cannot use a generic admin account: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tasks-that-require-root.html For reference the MFA serial number for your root account is: arn:aws:iam::<your-account-id>:mfa/root-account-mfa-device

Comment: i thought you are not supposed to use root account credentials with the aws cli.  is there an easy way to temporarily use the root account for that single put-bucket-versioning command?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have Root User Account Keys for CLI access, you can generate them using these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html#id_root-user_manage_add-key
Otherwise you get the error:

> An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: Mfa header is invalid

## Working example:

[image]

## Instructions:

Login to the CLI:

`aws configure`.

View the accounts S3 buckets:

```
aws s3 ls
```

List the Virtual MFA Devices:

```
aws iam list-virtual-mfa-devices
```

Using the S3 Bucket name, the virtual mfa device ARN and your google authenticate app to generate the mfa code, enter this command:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket <yourbucket> --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::<account number>:mfa/root-account-mfa-device <mfa code>"
```

## Result:

Check your bucket has MFA Delete Enabled:

[image]

## Rollback:

The operation can be reversed:

```
{
  "MFADelete": "Enabled"|"Disabled",
  "Status": "Enabled"|"Suspended"
}
```